# Make javac treat warnings as errors

Tags: java, ant, warnings, javac

I have an Ant file that compiles my program. I want the javac task to fail if any warning was reported by the compiler. Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: +1 because I'd have never thought to look.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `-Werror` flag. It's not listed in the `-help` output, but it works.

I found it through [this blog entry](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/tball/archive/2006/11/get_medieval_on.html) and tested on my own code (in NetBeans with Ant). The output was:

```
MyClass.java:38: warning: [serial] serializable class MyClass has no definition of serialVersionUID
public class MyClass extends JComponent {
1 warning
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Note that this is Java 6 only, though.

**Edit**: Example of specifying this in Ant buildfile:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath">
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>
    <compilerarg value="-Werror"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: And yes, it's probably not the best idea to combine -Werror with -Xlint like I was doing here.

Comment: Do you know how to specify javac.compilerargs directly in Ant buildfile? The blog post is a bit unclear on that.

Comment: Ah, found a way: the [<compilerarg> element](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). I took the liberty of adding an example to your answer.

Comment: Update: at least in Java 8, `-Werror` is now documented in `-help` ("Terminate compilation if warnings occur") and the [online docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), though it's documented with a lowercase `w` there (`-werror`).

Comment: `-werror` doesn't work for me, but `-Werror` does. My `-help` is showing `-Werror` too (I run `javac 1.8.0_121`).