# configure java compiler so that it gives an error on missing annotations

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations

how can i configure the javac compiler to give an error instead of a warning when an annotation like @Override is missing?

it should work on java 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-Werror` option with JDK 6.

---

**On the same topic :**

- [Javac: Treat warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040074/javac-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Comment: You can still try it. I saw some posts saying that it was available with the JDK 1.5. And if you have your code in Java5 but you're using JDK6 it will work.