# Eclipse (Java): Central "treat warnings as errors"

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to enable treat "treat warnings as errors" (or something similar that has the same effect) from a central location in eclipse?

I have already found Project Properties -> Errors/Warnings where I can change the error level for each individual warning (with corresponding effect in the Problems View). However I'd like to keep warnings being shown as warnings but have them prevent a sucessfull compile.

Comment: "Keep them as warnings but have them prevent a successful compile"?  In that context, what do you see as the difference between a warning that stops the compile, and an error?

Comment: @Andrzej: It keeps separate things separate: A warning usually tells you're violating a best practice, an error is something that renders  the compiler unable to further process the code. Treating warning as errors is an easy way to enforce (a minimum set of) best practices are followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your own ant script for compile and build and check this link (-Werror flag)
[Javac: Treat warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040074/javac-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this post when I was looking for a solution to treat warnings as errors in my Maven and Gradle Build. This post gave some basic answer to me, but post reading about JAVAC compiler options and maven compiler plugin. I have created a blog post explaining the importance of treating warnings as errors and how anyone could use JAVAC compiler options in their Maven and Gradle builds in my blog post.

[Treat Warnings As Errors In JAVA](https://www.aravindhu.com/software%20development/2021/03/18/treat-warnings-as-errors-in-java.html)

[Treat Warnings As Errors In Spring Boot project](https://www.aravindhu.com/software%20development/2021/03/20/spring-boot-treat-warnings-as-errors.html)