# Parameterized Lists in method signature

Tags: java, generics

Something like the following will not give me a compile-time or runtime error and I'm drawing a blank as to why.  Is there a way to enforce a compile error on the call to cls.add?

Why isn't the definition of T in the class definition being carried over to the call to the methods inside?  I understand I didn't instantiate the class that way, but the definition of the class states T must be a Number.

```
public class NewClass<T extends Number> {

    private List<T> id = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(List<T> elem) {
        id.addAll(elem);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass cls = new NewClass();
        cls.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a raw type. All type information is ignored in that case, and you get a warning.

If you provide a type parameter, it will fail:

```
NewClass<Integer> cls = new NewClass<Integer>();
cls.add(new ArrayList<String>()); //error
```

Comment: I figured it was related to the raw type usage.  I thought maybe there was a way to enforce the definition of T with something like 

public <T> void add(List<T> elem)

but no dice.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate cls, you need to provide the generic type, e.g.:

```
NewClass<Integer> cls = new NewClass<Integer>();
```

Comment: Nope, the check would still be on `cls` which also needs a generic type. You're still using the raw type.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in a warning since usage of generics is disabled in that case (you're using a raw type). Thats for backward compatibility reasons. You could make the compiler treat warnings as errors: [Javac: Treat warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040074/javac-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Comment: Good point.  Never thought about the treat warnings as errors setting.