# All warnings as errors with the Eclipse Java compiler (3.6.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

How do I treat warnings as errors with the Eclipse Java compiler (ECJ) 3.6.2<sup>*</sup> ***when running from the command-line***?

Newer versions (at least, 3.8.2) have the `-err:all` flag, however this isn't available in 3.6.2.  Do I have any other options?

I've found this question (*[Javac: Treat warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040074/javac-treat-warnings-as-errors)*) which recommends the undocumented `-Werror` flag, but that only seems to work for javac.

**Note:** For various reasons completely out of my control, I must use ECJ 3.6.2.  So switching to a newer version or javac is not an option (at least, not in the immediate future)!

---

<sub>* Also seems to be known as the ["JDT Core Batch Compiler"](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/details.php#JDTCORE).</sub>

Comment: I haven't tried, but there's a warn:none, maybe there's an undocumented -err:all?

Comment: @Benoir: It turns out you're right!  I was using a relatively old version of ECJ (3.6.2), but the latest version (3.8.2) does have an explicitly documented `-err:all` option.  I'll update my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to specify err:all, but there's a decent workaround:

1. Create an eclipse project.
2. Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Errors / Warnings.
3. Enable project specific settings.
4. Set everything to Error level by hand (annoying, but a one time operation).
5. That generates a org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file.
6. Use the project/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file in your compile process.

Here's an example using ant:

```
<javac srcdir="${test-unit.dir}" destdir="${target-test-classes.dir}" 
        classpathref="test.classpath" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true" 
        includeAntRuntime="false" compiler="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter">
    <compilerclasspath location="./libs/ecj-3.7.2.jar" />
    <compilerarg line="-time -properties .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs" />
</javac>
```