# Add org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file to compile

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I want to ask how should I include the project options in org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file in compile? Should I include it in the build.xml?

Comment: I think you should not include this type of file in your packaging. This file contains Eclipse properties that have no use for your application at runtime. Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I want to avoid all kinds of warnings and force eclipse to treat them as errors. I already have changed ant to fail when warnings are present.

Comment: Options in this preferences file are only for the Eclipse ECJ compiler, if you are using javac in your build.xml they are no use.

Comment: I want a better explanation on the comment on this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927376/all-warnings-as-errors-with-the-eclipse-java-compiler-3-6-2