# How Do I Prevent Usage of Deprecated Methods With Checkstyles

Tags: java, build, deprecated, checkstyle

Is there a straightforward way to have Checkstyle complain about the usage of deprecated methods? It seems like java provides some facility for this through XLint, but that seems to just produce warnings, and I'm not sure how to make that fail the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkstyle, FindBugs, and PMD can't do that out of the box.

But for this, the best detector is the `-deprecation` [compiler option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

CI tools can help you break the build whenever a deprecation warning appears in the compiler output. For instance, Jenkins has a [warnings plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) which may help. Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1040074/1005481) suggests using the `-Werror` compiler option, which treats all(!) warnings as errors.

Comment: These tools definitely should have support for code deprecation checkstyle